# Error #1050 Table 'name' already exists while I have an empty database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have a clean new mysql database on my localhost, and also I have a project built on codeigniter PHP framework and have a copy of that project database.

However, when I import the database into my clean new database I already created I get this error message :

```
SQL query:


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cr_addons`
--

CREATE TABLE `cr_addons` (
  `addon_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `addon_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addon_image` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive') DEFAULT 'Active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
MySQL said: Documentation

#1050 - Table 'cr_addons' already exists
```

How could I have to delete a table where I already have an empty database!
Working on my local machine with apache and mysql (XAMPP Stack)

Comment: Presumably the table *does* actually exist, have you tried refreshing your table list or disconnecting and reconnecting from the mysql server?

Comment: what's your default db inthe environment the query runs in? try adding the db prefix to the create table statement : CREATE TABLE prefix.cr_addons...

Comment: @GuyLouzon Those are my DB server info: 
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Make sure that the create table line is not duplicated somewhere in your file.

Comment: @aynber no it's not. But I just noticed that the MariaDB version of the source DB server is newer than mine. it's version 10.3.12 while mine is 10.1.38. This versions conflict may cause these kind of problems ?

Answer (score 2):

Execute

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database_name`;
USE `database_name`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cr_addons`;
CREATE TABLE `cr_addons` (
  `addon_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `addon_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addon_image` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive') DEFAULT 'Active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: There is no tables at all in my DB.

Answer (score 1):

You're new database might now be the default to be use my your client

Try setting the default DB schema by:

```
USE new_db;
```

Or either explicitly defining in which schema the table is created in:

```
CREATE TABLE new_db.`cr_addons` (
  `addon_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `addon_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addon_image` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive') DEFAULT 'Active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I use is to re-export the database from production server. Initial export is possibly corrupt.